# Getting page title from URL in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I was hoping this would be an easy one, but it seems to break my code!

I am trying to make an `<h1>` out of the URL, with this:

```
$scope.pageTitle = $scope.$watch(function() {
    $scope.pageTitle = $location.url().substring(1);
  };
```

Then in my view, use this:

```
<h1>{{pageTitle}}</h1>
```

Why doesn't this work?!

Thanks to anyone who can help me get my head round this!

JP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the answer! Whoo!

```
$scope.location = $location;

  $scope.$watch('location.url()', getTitle);

  function getTitle() {
    $scope.pageTitle = $location.url().substring(1);
  };
```